# Linux replace space to newline for a string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a string and I am trying to replace the space to newline

my original string

```
xxx xxx xxx xxx
```

If I use the following command then it works

```
echo $string | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

However if I want to assign the new string to another variable e.g.

```
newString=`echo $string | sed 's/ /\n/g'`
echo $newString
```

It doesn't work...

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that this:

```
echo $newString
```

means "take the value of `$newString`, perform word splitting and filename expansions, and pass the result as zero or more arguments to `echo`". The result of word splitting `$'xxx\nxxx\nxxx\nxxx'` is four separate `xxx` arguments, so your command amounts to `echo xxx xxx xxx xxx`.

Instead, you want:

```
echo "$newString"
```

which means "take the value of `$newString` and pass it as a single argument to `echo`".

---

Incidentally, if you're just replacing a character in a string, you don't need to use `sed`. Bash supports this as built-in functionality. Instead of this:

```
newString=`echo $string | sed 's/ /\n/g'`
```

you can write this:

```
newString="${string// /$'\n'}"
```

(The general pattern being `${variable_name//string_to_replace/replacement_string}`.